# Upgrading to Rails 3: <%= if expression %> raising error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, rails-3-upgrade

Ok looking over some podcasts I've seen that in Rails 3, we need to use the `<%= %>` tag now when we didn't before. However just putting this in my application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>  
  <%= if true %>
true        
  <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

does not render 'true' as I expected. Instead I get an error:

```
Showing /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
  ');@output_buffer.append= ( if true );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
                                       ^
/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
');   end 
         ^
/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
3: <head></head>
4: <body>  
5:   <%= if true %>
6: true        
7:   <% end %>
8: </body>
```

going back to the old `<% %>` tag fixes this problem. Is this correct? Did the rails developers decide to switch back to the old tag or am I missing something?

`rails -v` gets me: `Rails 3.0.5`

Any ideas?

Comment: This only applies to some tags like `form_for`. In this case you just use `<% if true %>`.

Comment: ok well post that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Tried to explain why you have to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>` for `form_for`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This only applies to some tags. E.g. `<% form_for ... %>` became `<%= form_for ... %>`. In this case you just use `<% if true %>`. The reason is that `form_for` generates output, so you use `<%= %>`. A simple if statement does not generate output, so you use `<% %>`. The same goes for loops etc.: you just keep using `<% %>`.

It is explained [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3) too:

> form_for will insert form tags into
>   the view around the content in the
>   block, but there is no equals sign in
>   the erb tags. This breaks the rule
>   that erb blocks that output code to
>   the view should use <%= %> and has
>   made this difficult to work with the
>   internals of form_for in previous
>   versions of Rails. From [Rails
>   version 3] onwards, however, we use an
>   equals signs here as we would with any
>   other erb code that generates output.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>  
  <% if true %>
true        
  <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```